# Find $6^{s}$ complement of $N=(268)_{10}$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

### Question

> Find $6^{s}$ complement of  $N=(268)_{10}$

#### My approach

> First i converted $N=(268)_{10}$ to $(1124)_{6}$

then ,

> i found the $6^{s}$ complement by subtrating $N$ from $r^{n}$

where **$r$**=base

$n$=number of digit

which is

> $6^{4}-1124$=$1296-1124$=$172$

which seems to be incorrect  because if i do using diminished radix complement

i.e using $5^{s}$ complement and then adding $1$ ,it is coming as-:

$(5555-N)$+$1$=$(5555-1124)+1$=$4432$

I am confused.

Please help me out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the number $ N $ is written in base (or radix) $ r $. The [radix complement of $ N $ is by definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements#Numeric_complements)

$$r^n-N=\left((r^n-1)-N\right)+1, \tag{1}$$

where $ n $ is the number of digits of $ N $.

Your error is in

> $6^{4}-1124$=$1296-1124$=$172$

because the number $1124 $ is written in base $6$, while $1296 =6^4 $ is written in base $10$. Since $(6^4)_6=(10000)_6 $ you should have:

$$(6^4)_6-(1124)_6=(10000)_6 - ( 1124)_6 = (4432)_6. \tag{2}$$

Alternatively, for $ r=6$ and $N=(1124)_6$, $ n=4 $. And since $(6^4)_6-(1)_6=(5555)_6$,  we obtain from $(1) $ the same result, confirming your last computation

$$\begin{align}(6^4)_6-(1124)_6&=((6^4)_6-(1)_6)-(1124)_6+(1 )_6 \\
&=(5555)_6-(1124)_6+(1)_6 \\&= (4431)_6+(1)_6\\&=(4432)_6.\tag{3}\end{align}$$